# Filter one combination from 6 combinations in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

So I have this array of objects which consists of items where one item have 6 combinations which are posed as objects.

Suppose I have one combination of this object:

```
{ "1": "ab", "2": "bc", "3": "ac" }
```

The array also consists of 5 other objects with different combinations of that object. Like this:

```
{ "1": "ab", "2": "ac", "3": "bc" }
{ "1": "ac", "2": "bc", "3": "ab" }
{ "1": "ac", "2": "ab", "3": "bc" }
{ "1": "bc", "2": "ac", "3": "ab" }
{ "1": "bc", "2": "ab", "3": "ac" }
```

This way I have around 1000 items with 6 combinations of each of them in an array and I need to filter and return only 1 combination of each item.

So suppose this is an array of 12 different combinations of two items:

```
[
    { "1": "ab", "2": "bc", "3": "ac" }
    { "1": "ab", "2": "ac", "3": "bc" }
    { "1": "ac", "2": "bc", "3": "ab" }
    { "1": "ac", "2": "ab", "3": "bc" }
    { "1": "bc", "2": "ac", "3": "ab" }
    { "1": "bc", "2": "ab", "3": "ac" }

    { "1": "de", "2": "ef", "3": "df" }
    { "1": "df", "2": "ef", "3": "de" }
    { "1": "de", "2": "df", "3": "ef" }
    { "1": "ef", "2": "df", "3": "de" }
    { "1": "df", "2": "de", "3": "ef" }
    { "1": "ef", "2": "de", "3": "df" }
]
```

I want to filter that array and return only 1 combination of each, like so:

```
[
    { "1": "ab", "2": "bc", "3": "ac" }
    { "1": "de", "2": "ef", "3": "df" }
]
```

Please note that "ab" in first object can be a value in whole different combination like:

```
{ "1": "ab", "2": "df", "3": "fe" }
```

How can I do this efficiently and with good performance in mind?

Comment: are the values always strings?

Comment: Yes. Always string.

Comment: What is your criteria of making the selection? Are the array elements always in the right order

Comment: It could be in any order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values are always strings you can create a composite key from the sorted [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) of each element and then use a simple 'group by' operation, here using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) accumulating into a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

I'm only setting on the first match here (only if the map doesn't have a matching entry) which will return the first match, if you want the last match, just set the key on every iteration.

```js
const input = [
  { 1: 'ab', 2: 'bc', 3: 'ac' },
  { 1: 'ab', 2: 'ac', 3: 'bc' },
  { 1: 'ac', 2: 'bc', 3: 'ab' },
  { 1: 'ac', 2: 'ab', 3: 'bc' },
  { 1: 'bc', 2: 'ac', 3: 'ab' },
  { 1: 'bc', 2: 'ab', 3: 'ac' },

  { 1: 'de', 2: 'ef', 3: 'df' },
  { 1: 'df', 2: 'ef', 3: 'de' },
  { 1: 'de', 2: 'df', 3: 'ef' },
  { 1: 'ef', 2: 'df', 3: 'de' },
  { 1: 'df', 2: 'de', 3: 'ef' },
  { 1: 'ef', 2: 'de', 3: 'df' },
];

const result = [
  ...input
    .reduce((a, o) => {
      const key = Object.values(o)
        .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
        .join('_');

      if (!a.has(key)) a.set(key, o);

      return a;
    }, new Map())
    .values(),
];

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you don't mind returning the last matched combination you can simplify this into a `map()` within a `new Map()` call.

```js
const input = [{ 1: 'ab', 2: 'bc', 3: 'ac' }, { 1: 'ab', 2: 'ac', 3: 'bc' }, { 1: 'ac', 2: 'bc', 3: 'ab' }, { 1: 'ac', 2: 'ab', 3: 'bc' }, { 1: 'bc', 2: 'ac', 3: 'ab' }, { 1: 'bc', 2: 'ab', 3: 'ac' }, { 1: 'de', 2: 'ef', 3: 'df' }, { 1: 'df', 2: 'ef', 3: 'de' }, { 1: 'de', 2: 'df', 3: 'ef' }, { 1: 'ef', 2: 'df', 3: 'de' }, { 1: 'df', 2: 'de', 3: 'ef' }, { 1: 'ef', 2: 'de', 3: 'df' },];

const result = [
  ...new Map(
    input.map((o) => [
      Object.values(o)
        .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
        .join('_'),
      o,
    ])
  ).values(),
];

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Here's a quick example of how you might sort the result array returned by the filter. It's just a function that accepts a [compare function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description), sorts the `Object.values` of the passed combination object and then rebuilds the object from the sorted array of values (here using `Object.fromEntries()`, but if you don't mind 0 indexed objects you could use `Object.assign()` and forego the extra `map()`, ie. `return Object.assign({}, Object.values(obj).sort(compare));`)

```js
const input = [
  { 1: 'ab', 2: 'bc', 3: 'ac' },
  { 1: 'ab', 2: 'ac', 3: 'bc' },
  { 1: 'ac', 2: 'bc', 3: 'ab' },
  { 1: 'ac', 2: 'ab', 3: 'bc' },
  { 1: 'bc', 2: 'ac', 3: 'ab' },
  { 1: 'bc', 2: 'ab', 3: 'ac' },

  { 1: 'de', 2: 'ef', 3: 'dc' },
  { 1: 'dc', 2: 'ef', 3: 'de' },
  { 1: 'de', 2: 'dc', 3: 'ef' },
  { 1: 'ef', 2: 'dc', 3: 'de' },
  { 1: 'dc', 2: 'de', 3: 'ef' },
  { 1: 'ef', 2: 'de', 3: 'dc' },
];

const result = [...new Map(input.map((o) => [Object.values(o).sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)).join('_'), o,])).values(),];
console.log('Initial result: ', result);

function sort_combination(obj, compare = (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.values(obj)
      .sort(compare)
      .map((v, i) => [i + 1, v])
  );
}

const includes_c = (a, b) => b.includes('c') - a.includes('c') || a.localeCompare(b);

const sorted = result.map((o) => sort_combination(o, includes_c));

console.log('Sorted result: ', sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hey man. Sorry to bother you gain but what if I want different order?

Comment: How do you propose indicating what order you want?

Comment: No I mean in the first snippet its ab bc ac but what if I want bc ac ab or ac bc ab?

Comment: I understand, but how do you want to indicate that in code? will you pass the desired order? Once you have the reduced array you can order the properties as you choose, no need to return a specific one from the filter.

Comment: Umm suppose I have 1 thing in common in all the combination. Suppose c is in every combination in all the items of the array. And I want that combination which includes c to be at the first pair. Like ac ab bc or ec df dc. Sorry I failed to mention this in the OP